# Handle a form reset to initial values in React with controlled components?

Tags: reactjs

I've currently got a form built with controlled components using React. I am trying to support a 'discard changes' feature so that as soon as any of the form fields change, the discard changes button pops up and the user can clear back the form to the initial state it was in.

Currently, I'm carrying around three state variables to make this happen and the solution feels sucky.

I can't just populate a simple initial values object that matches the form fields because the form gets filled in initially from an API call within useEffect that sets up my form.

It's at this moment currently that I am doing something like (psuedo-code):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        setFormData(settingsData);
        setCurrentFormData(settingsData);
  }, []);
```

And then in my onChange:

```
  const handleChange = (value, id) => {
    setIsDirty(true);
    setFormData((prevFormData) => {
      return {
        ...prevFormData,
        [id]: value,
      };
    });
  };
```

my onSubmit:

```
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    fetch("/settings-data", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(formData),
    }).then(function (response) {
      setCurrentFormData(formData);
      setIsDirty(false);
    });
  };
```

and my handleDiscard:

```
  const handleDiscard = (e) => {
    setFormData(currentFormData);
    setIsDirty(false);
  };
```

Just feels like there may be a better way to do this without having to manage these three variables. Any ideas for a better solution?